# how do I use svn in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to create my own *SVN* server so I can work on my android projects everywhere.

I have an VPS and I installed svn, I set up the directory and added a use to the password file.

After a while I finally managed to create a project with

```
svn import -m "initial import" . file:///home/admin/svn/reposvn/testp/trunk
```

But I don't understand?
Can I only import project that are on my server?
If thats the case I could just use ftp and not worry about svn at all.

What I would like to do is have a url to use in things like eclipse.
my subdomain points to `/home/admin/svn/` and then I typed in `/reposvn`

So I tried the urls

```
http://(mydomain)/reposvn
```

and

```
svn://(mydomain)/reposvn
```

but neither worked
Says
Detected a cycle while processing the operation
svn: Redirected cycle detected for URL ....

I also set up daemon or whatever with svnserve -d

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I wrote an article about this. I think it will give you enough information about this issue: [How to set up SVN version control over SSL with Apache to use in Eclipse.](http://www.devgems.net/?p=107)

Comment: I know my eclipse is set up correctly and I believe I set up svn correctly because on the server it works fine. My problem is trying to use svn remotely. I dont know if I am suppose to use http:// ot svn:// or what.

Comment: And what is your Apache configuration? In my example there is a step by step explanation about how to configure this, once for http and once for https.

Comment: Seems the problem was I was trying to use svn daemon and not Apache. Thanks though! I didn't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it working
One of the thing that took me a while to figure out is that svn:// is for the svnserve daemon
where the http:// access has to be set up through Apache.

I deleted my entire svn and reinstall / re set up everything, so there might have been some sort of messed up configuration.

However I set up the daemon with

```
svnserve -d --foreground -r /home/admin/svn
```

and then I was able to connect with svn://

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

Thanks